# What's the deal with exophoric pronoun references?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

I have been reading about errors with exophoric pronoun references (the paper was mostly aimed at preparing one for a certain standardized test), and found the author saying "In the context of this test, exophoric pronouns are **always** incorrect." So I have two questions:

1) Just to make sure that I understand exophoric pronoun references correctly, I am wondering if something like

> John went outside in the middle of the day. He found the weather to be calming and relaxing.

would be incorrect within the context of the standardized test? It looks very natural to me, but I think that's because in my native tongue such a reference is acceptable ("he" is exophoric here, am I right?)

2) How unwelcome are the exophoric references in general? Is it just this test being picky, or should I refrain from using them elsewhere?

Comment: My understanding of exophoric pronouns is that they refer to subjects that *do not appear in the text*. In other words they must be deduced by context. But John *does* appear in the text. So I don't think the 'he' in your second sentence is exophoric.

Comment: It is unclear what your text is. How do we know what the 'context' of the mentioned context is? 'Incorrect' seems extreme no matter what. Also, is this in reference to a text or to speech? For 'That is a really big chair' in text, 'that' has no possible -physical- referent. Also, this may be better asked at linguistics.stackexchange.com since it is not English specific.

Comment: General reference. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exophora

Comment: @StoneyB- actually I think 'her' is exophoric with respect to your quoted text.  Probably just a typo?

Comment: @Jim, yes, [blush], thank you. I'm going to delete it ...  
"John went outside in the middle of the day. It was then that he saw her." - Here, *her* is exophoric with respect to the quoted text because it refers to a woman not otherwise mentioned. What's not clear from your example is what texts - question? multiple-choice answer? written answer? - are considered; could you post an example from the test which the paper tells you exhibits this error?

Comment: The 'he' in that text is anaphoric, not exophoric as it refers back to something previously mentioned, i.e. John. Exophora is reference to something (in some sense) outside of the text, e.g. deixis. I'm not sure this is a good question as it seems it might rely on knowing about the paper and the test so a more detailed answer would require guessing.

Comment: Just saw the other comments after posting mine! @StoneyB 'her' in that utterance could well be cataphoric (i.e. a forward reference) if the 'her' is mentioned later--we can't tell unless we have the whole utterance/text. Re the downvote, it wasn't me, but maybe it was due to your  (exophoric?) references to contents of the paper and test (see my previous comment).

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut It could be, yes, *or* exophoric; that's why I qualified it as 'with respect to the quoted text'. . . Doesn't 'anaphoric' mean it refers to something *subsequently* mentioned?

Comment: @StoneyB Anaphora is reference backwards, ie to something previously mentioned.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut You're right, my apologies; I was thinking of *cataphora*.

Comment: Anaphoric, cataphoric, exophoric … add to those _endophoric_ (referring to something mentioned inside the pronoun) and _metaphoric_ (referring to something scribbled above the line). ;-)   [Disclaimer: That was a joke, of course. _Endophoric_ is really just the opposite of _exophoric_, and _metaphoric_ is not used in this sense at all.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example, the pronoun "he" that begins the second sentence is not exophoric. It is endophoric, because its referent is manifest in the text.

> "In discourse in general, the third person pronouns may be either *endophoric*, referring to a noun phrase within the text, . . . or *exophoric*, referring to someone or something manifest to the participants from the situation or from their mutual knowledge ('Here he is,' for example, on seeing someone who both sender and receiver are expecting). . . . [citation](http://grammar.about.com/od/e/g/exophoraterm.htm).

What your test instructions admonish you to do is to forego exophoric pronouns that may seem obvious to you but are not to others.

> "They say cells never die; they only divide."

In the above sentence, *they* could be exophoric or endophoric. If it referred to scientists who did the research and wrote the paper (and therefore are referenced in it), it is endophoric. If it is a general statement about some unnamed scientists somewhere (or the elusive "they" who are responsible for all rumored activities), which the author assumes to be obvious to the reader, then it is exophoric. Just make sure you use pronouns that refer to real persons or things in your text.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like the context for the referent (within this test) is defined as the sentence, and not the text as a whole. I'll make sure to double check.

Comment: According to [this](http://people.umass.edu/gmhwww/595/pdf/book/$10-Pronouns.pdf), it would seem pronouns are usually classified as *exophoric* or ***anaphoric***.

Comment: If "they" refers to the set of all people who say such a thing, is it reflexophoric?

Answer (score 0):

An exophoric pronoun is one that lies outside the the text and relies on shared knowledge between the speaker and the reader/listener, so your 'he' is not exophoric as 'John' has been mentioned in the text. A convenient way to visualise the idea of an exophoric pronoun is that you would need to point if you were speaking ~ "Those plants look nice" while pointing at the plants.

What the author is trying to say is that exophoric pronouns in a written test are unwelcome, as the reader/examiner has no way of knowing what they refer to.

Comment: Many exophoric pronouns are deictic, but not all.

Comment: Can you give an example of an exophoric pronoun that is not deictic?

Comment: Sure: *her* in  "John went outside in the middle of the day. It was then that he saw her." There's no reference to the context of the utterance here.

Comment: How do you interpret 'her' without extralinguistic context? To know who 'her' is, you need to know who is speaking, or when and where they are speaking, or the speaker will need to point. It is exophoric because 'her' is outside the text, and deictic because the semantic meaning of 'her' is fixed but the denotational meaning depends on the context.

Comment: Perhaps the meaning of *deictic* has changed. In my day it meant *referring to the circumstances of the discourse itself*. *You* and *I* are deictic, because they refer to the persons conversing. *Her*, in my example, would be deictic only if the person referred to were physically present during the conversation.

Comment: That is quite different to my understanding, but the concept of deixis does seem to be quite varied depending on your field. As I understand it, deixis is the situation where the semantic meaning of the word, as found in a dictionary, differs to the denotative meaning, as in what it points at (deixis = point)in the physical world. 'Her' from a dictionary would be something like "3rd person feminine objective pronoun", but to know which physical female it points requires contextual information..

Answer (score 0):

"John went outside in the middle of the day. He found the weather to be calming and relaxing".

In the case of the above sentence, "He" is a personal pronoun refers back to "John" so that it is Anaphoric reference.

More examples:

I went to school yesterday. Then, I met some of my friends. "I" here is a personal pronoun refers exophorically. *We* meaning *You* and *I* can work as Anaphoric sometimes. For example, My girlfriend and I traveled to Brisbane. We saw many things. "WE" here is anaphorically refers to "My girlfriend and I" so it is an anaphoric reference but not exophoric one.

Reading Halliday and Hasan`s theory "Cohesion in English, 1976" is going to enrich and enlighten your thought in regard to Reference.

Answer (score 0):

Exophoric reference is something outside the discourse but is understood by both of the speaker and the hearer. Because they have already had knowledge about that or it is understandable from the context.
     Example:
Donald Trump is the 45th Presisent of the United States.
--> So "Donald Trump" is exophoric reference in this sentence because it wasn't mentioned earlier or later in the discourse but we still understand who is the speaker are referring to, right? :)))

--> He in your example is not exophoric reference. It is anaphoric reference because "he" refers to "John" which is mentioned earlier in the discourse. And if "John" is mentioned later, "he" will be cataphoric reference.